# Can I share a finding in the shape of answered question for future reference?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes, I can't find answers to my questions, then later, I stumble across the solution either by accident or trial and error.

On the bright side, I have solved my problem, while on the dark side, I would forget the way I solved it. So how acceptable is it to ask a question then answer it to be a future reference for me and anyone else comes across the same inquiry?

Comment: This is acceptable and encouraged, but I consider it polite to not post the self-answer straight away, but rather to post the question, wait a day or two to give others a chance to answer, and then post your self-answer if nothing better has been posted in the meantime. See http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4/asking-a-question-and-answering-it-yourself-straight-away

Comment: Thanks for referring to that question, I didn't see it before asking. I will consider your comment later on.

Comment: There's even a badge for it if you get enough votes on your answer (self-learner). Just don't abuse it. There are some people who will look down on it however long you wait and however good the question or answer, but the rules are emphatically on your side. Nobody will appreciate a banal question with an equally tedious answer if it feels like you're just farming rep points, though, of course :)

Comment: I understand. The main issue is that some answers are not straightforward and can't be easily found among the huge TEX.SX database. The problem is I already know the answer before I even put the question for future reference, so I am afraid to be  considered something ridiculous to ask a question whose answer is known to the OP.

Comment: (1) I think there is *prima facie* reason not to ask a question to which you already know the answer unless you are asking for improvement or whatever. There may be exceptions, but generally. (2) If, however, you find an answer to a question you've asked, absolutely answer it. (1*) If you think you have an exception, make clear that you intend to answer it in the question. Nothing more annoying that trying to solve a problem for somebody who already knows how to solve it! But you need to be open to other approaches/better answers. (3) Obviously, don't duplicate answers found on this site.

Comment: It is true that the rules support asking-in-order-to-answer. However, the rules are also rather stricter than this site on which questions are OK at all. A question you ask to answer should be of broad interest and concern a significant issue. However, I'm getting the impression, you're talking about answers you find *on this site*. But the rules certainly do *not* encourage creating duplicate questions deliberately, even though the value of inadvertently-created duplicates is recognised. (But duplication applies to *questions* and not, as I understand it, to *answers*.)

Comment: I understand your point. For example, I tried to understand how to generate PDF and aux files in two separate folders by both `latexmk` and TexStudio, then after going through different questions and answers, I totally figured it out. So, the good way to keep it for future reference is to be put in the form of answered question. It is good to do some research before asking and solve the problem, and it is also ridiculous to ask then answer. Apparently, it seems to be bad idea to do so.

Comment: We also had a discussion about "deliberate duplicates" before [Asking existing questions differently to improve findability](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6419/35864). In general, I don't think asking questions you know the answer to is bad, but you should make sure the question you ask is useful to others and as widely applicable as possible (and maybe warn other people that you know the answer in the comments). Make sure that you [ask a good question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) then and [give a good answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If the question might be interesting for future readers, asking and selfanswering a question is absolutely a good idea. For example I do this, when I misunderstood a question and delete my answer there. If I think my answer might help someone else, I post a new Q&A to keep the answer around. But I disagree with @Jake: If you already know the answer, post it straight away and don't wait. If someone thinks he knows another answer, he will add one. But if you wait, you waste the time people who are trying to figure out an answer for you believing they would help you.

Comment: Now, I am more confused :). I believe my Q/A is beneficial for new users especially, and I need to keep it in the form of Q/A for me as a future reference. I just don't want to be reprimanded for doing so.

Comment: If I wanted to do so, what title form should I follow? Is it good to make the title a normal question or what?

Comment: I'd make it a "normal" Q&A: Choose a good title that summarises the question, just as you would for any other question you ask.

Comment: I'd say that the consensus of the comments is that you are welcome to ask a question you know the answer to and answer it yourself. Just make sure that the question is non-trivial, useful to others and widely applicable, that is not just specific to one particular problem you were facing. Please take some time to write a good question and a useful answer.

Comment: I understand. I will try to formulate it in a good tutorial shape.

Comment: You can add a comment to your own question saying: *This question and answer is to add useful information for others. I don't need support on that now. If nobody answers, i add an answer myself.* We do that on a German Q-A site, and it works quite well.

Comment: @Johannes_B, Good point.

Comment: Imho it is quite ok to add good questions and answers. It enlarge the knowledge base. I asked such a question once and put a large warning at the start: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258978/the-same-bibliography-with-different-sorting. (I hadn't to add my own answer as it was answered from someone else).

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, thanks for sharing. I will consider what you did.